# Can the effect of a certain devil fruit last through the effect of another devil fruit?

Tags: one-piece

Just to make it easy to understand my question here is the example below :

Suppose a person **X**

A User of the *Modo Modo no Mi* use his/her **DF** ability and make **X** younger by 12 years,

now another **DF** user (lets say) of the *Toki Toki no Mi* use his/her **DF** ability & sends **X** (who is 12 years younger because of the effect of the earlier **DF**) into the future...

my question is that, will the *Modo Modo no Mi* maintain its effect on **X** who was sent into the future or not ?

Answer (score 2):

There are no known facts at the moment that support which way is the correct one.

But if I am to make an educated guess, I think the **answer is no**. I think that most Devil Fruits in One Piece have an "ability range" meaning that if one can manipulate the objects near him, they will remain modified as long as they are in this "range" of the Devil Fruit.

For ex: The DF of *vice-admiral Tsuru*, [Woshu Woshu no Mi](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Woshu_Woshu_no_Mi), allows the user to literally "wash and hang out to dry" people and objects as if they were clothes. I can't imagine that if she chooses so, those people will remain like that for the rest of their lives. Same goes with *Trafalgar Law's* ability or *Sugar* from Dressrossa. They have to be in a reasonable range so that their respective DF powers work.

At least that is how I imagine the OP world works because otherwise it would be total chaos and we haven't seen any other character that had traces of a Devil Fruit ability on them that was used in the past (not their own DF powers of course). And to answer your question, the person sent in the future will automatically revert to their original nature and nullify any other DF abilities that were used upon them.

Comment: While I do Agree with most of what you've said. When you say that an ability will cease if it's not within "ability range", then how come Trafalgar Law's DF allows him to grant someone immortality with the cost of his own life (DF  user dies but ability lingers and remains)... so in other words the rules that apply to each DF is different depending on the DF?
This raises so many questions tbh

Comment: @LearningDev probably his DF is an exception and that is why it is considered one of a kind in One Piece. It is even described as the "Ultimate Devil Fruit" in chapter 761 so it's kind of the exception that strengthens the rule :D

Comment: hummm its a bit confusing to wrap my head around since Blackbeard's DF is also an 'exception' if you get me. But still thx for thinking along :D

Comment: @LearningDev Probabily not even Oda thought about it this far :)

Comment: haha I'd say he knows, he's full of surprises after all :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, yes. In your example, let's say X was originally 20 yrs old. He was made 12 yrs younger so is now 8 yrs old physically in the current timeline. Let's say he was sent 100 yrs into the future. Your question then is, will he remain 8 yrs old physically in this future or not?

My guess is yes - he should remain 8 yrs old. I don't think he would be 120 (which is his "real" age had he lived through the entire time) nor 108 yrs old (which is not what happened to Momonosuke and group).

...But like so many other questions in One Piece, it's just my speculation and will remain so unless Oda-sensei confirms it.

Comment: That's what I originally thought but, the Modo Modo no Mi would have changed users if a 100 years had passed (lets assume ), and we know that even something as simple as knocking out the **DF** user would make their ability cease (for e.g. Sugar) , so following the example, its difficult to believe that the Modo Modo no Mi ability would not cease if **X** was sent 100 years into the future. I was hoping someone can provide a logical answer with proof and might know something I might've missed in the series, but as you've said unless Oda confirms it somehow, I can only wait :(

Comment: Sorry if my answer doesn't help.That's the problem with so many questions in One Piece - only a few of them actually get confirmed, if at all. Sugar's DF is just one of the few exceptions. Majority of DF effects remain permanent like the Toki Toki. I have been watching since 1999 and also started reading the manga about 10 yrs ago, but only very few questions have been answered so far. Also there is no guarantee that all will be revealed when One Piece ends...

Comment: Its ok man, don't be sorry, I was just stating that your reply is just what I was thinking, that's all :) 
and yes you're right, as time goes by things start to make sense (its just that in one piece's case I might be 90 years old before all my questions are answered lol)

Comment: I think there is no logic behind devil fruit powers and abilities.

Answer (score 0):

I will side with VXD here. Although, RigaCrypto puts some valid points there. But they don't help much with the answers.

Once a permanent change has been made in the OP world by using a Devil Fruit(DF) it has to be manually countered or complemented.

> Exhibit A: Kin'emon and his torso => Punk Hazard.
>  Exhibit B:
>   Fugitora's Meteor shower from Dressroza.

Hence, Yes X will be younger  in the future. Not the other way around. Most devil fruits don't have limitations of their own but it's upon the user as to how much he can utilize the DF. But those with limitations like time or space are mostly defined.

> Exhibit C: Foxy ate the Noro Noro no Mi, a Paramecia-type Devil Fruit
>   which allows him to fire microscopic particles as beams of light that
>   can slow down his enemies or other objects for 30 seconds (he
>   demonstrates this by slowing down a cannon ball fired at him, only to
>   get hit by the cannonball anyway when he was gloating over its power
>   for too long)